# Three.js Canvas rendering

Tags: three.js

I have a question about Three.js with Canvas rendering:
I use Canvas rendering for be full compatible, the speed is not important for me, but i have two viewport, each with same scene, and a textured object render only in one view, depending of the rendering order :( I am block on it since one week , so ,it si normal "feature" ?

Comment: If i use two scene with same data, that's will work ? i hope other solution exist

Comment: This is a known feature limitation. Sadly you need to load the scene (and textures twice).

Comment: okay,so i know ui search a ghost :) thank you for fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up two separate renderers, attach them to separate HTML elements, and use CSS `z-index` to layer them on top of each other. As Mr. Doob commented, it won't save you any computation memory.

It is cool because you can use the same scene (mesh, material, lights), but different cameras.